# Blog Post Title and Read more Button doesn't link to post

Tags: magento-1.9, blog

I'm using Magento 1.9 and have a blog setup but whenever i create a post the post itself doesn't link to a separate page containing the full post instead of redirects to the index page. See below for an example:

[http://website.co.uk/blog](http://stage.waxmanarchitectural.co.uk/blog)

the post should be linked to the following link:

[http://website.co.uk/blog/test](http://stage.waxmanarchitectural.co.uk/blog/test)

but as you can see it says 404 Not Found yet the post exists in the Backend.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a very simple fix, it was a mistake on my behalf. If your experiencing this problem and are a newbie like me then please make sure that in the Blog Settings that the field for "**Route to Blog**" has no "/" in it as it throws the URL off and redirects to the main page.